# PHP upload via FTP - ftp_put() I won't open a connection to x.x.x.x (only to y.y.y.y)

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to use one host to upload content to another via FTP.

The "*I won't open a connection to 172.xxx.xxx.xxx (only to 54.xxx.xxx.xxx)*" is not even relevant because I am not connecting to that host. That's the IP address to the server that is hosting the script. But not to the server that is being accessed via FTP.

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect('50.xxx.xxx.xxx');
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'user', 'pass');

$file = "http://example.com/filelocation.swf";

if (ftp_put($conn_id, "test.swf", $file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo 'File Uploaded'; 
} 
else {
    echo 'Problem with uploading'; 
}
```

> ftp_put() I won't open a connection to 172.xxx.xxx.xxx (only to 54.xxx.xxx.xxx)

The IP addresses within this error, does not go to the server I am trying to connect to. The `ftp_login` connects and no issues. ( I don't even want it to make a connection to those IP addresses anyways, so why does it even think that?)

I can use `ftp_mkdir` to add a directory on the server. However, when I use `ftp_put`, it throws that error.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The error message is actually very relevant.

It's Pure-FTPd error response to `PORT` command, when the client is asking the server to open a data connection to an IP address different to that of the client (as the server sees it). So it's a remote error message sent by the server, not a local error message produced by PHP.

The problem is typically caused by the client knowing only its local IP address, not the external IP address.

---

Now, the question is why PHP uses `PORT`, when you asked it to connect using passive mode (`ftp_pasv`).

It's clearly because you call `ftp_pasv` before even logging in.

So the server rejects the `PASV` call with:

> 530 You aren't logged in

Unfortunately the PHP does not propagate error messages from `PASV` call. And it silently falls back to the default active mode. You can tell the call failed by its return value (that you do not check).

---

Just move the `ftp_pasv` call after the `ftp_login`.

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect('50.xx.xx.xx');

ftp_login($conn_id, 'user', 'pass');

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```

[The documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php) clearly suggests it:

> Please note that ftp_pasv() can only be called after a successful login or otherwise it will fail.

---

And of course, you should do a better error checking.

---

For a similar issue (just with ProFTPd), see:
[PHP ftp_put returning "Unable to build data connection: Connection refused"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42515533/850848)

Comment: That has solved the issue. ftp_pasv() should of been called after the login, instead of just the connection. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having an issue and to add to [Martin Prikryl's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl) answer, try calling `ftp_pasv` just before the connection and just after the connection too.

Comment: The `ftp_pasv` has to be called after the `ftp_login`. Calling it additionally earlier has no effect .

Comment: Following testing, our script does not work with it only called after and does not work when only called after, but does work when called immediately before and immediately after.