# PHP ftp_put returning "Unable to build data connection: Connection refused"

Tags: php, ftp

I have a PC that is running some FTP via PHP that I know used to work 1-2 months ago, but now I return to it I find that the PC is no longer working. I know I have been using the PC but I cannot think of what might have changed.

The PHP is throwing out error messages reading

> Unable to build data connection: Connection refused

...when I use the `ftp_put()` function.

The cut down code I am using is:

```
<?php

$trackErrors = ini_get('track_errors');
ini_set('track_errors', 1);

$server="***.***.***.***";
$port=21; 
echo "<LI>Connecting to $server:$port<BR>";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($server,$port,9999999) or die("<BR>Unable to connect to ".$server.":$port server.");
if ( !$conn_id ) {
    $errmsg = $php_errormsg;
    echo "<BR><LI>ERR:$errmsg";
}
else {
    $passive=false;
    echo "<LI>Setting Passive Mode=$passive";
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, $passive);

    $user="*********";
    $pass="*********";
    echo "<LI>Connecting as $user/*****";
    if (!ftp_login($conn_id, $user, $pass)) { 
        $msg = "Failed to login to $selected_server as $user; <BR>check logincredentials in the Settings";
        echo "<BR><LI>$msg";

        $errmsg = $php_errormsg;
        echo "<LI>ERR:$errmsg";
        return $msg;
    }

    ftp_set_option($conn_id, FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 10000);
    

    if (!@ftp_put($conn_id, "test.txt", "C:......test.txt", FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo "<BR><LI>ftp_put failed";

        $errmsg = $php_errormsg;
        echo "<LI>ERR:$errmsg";
    }
    echo "<HR>Done";
}
?>
```

the output when running this as a webpage is

```
Connecting to ***.***.***.***:21
Setting Passive Mode=
Connecting as *******/*****
ftp_put failed
ERR:ftp_put(): Unable to build data connection: Connection refused
Done
```

The result is that the `ftp_put()` gives the error message and leaves a zero (0) byte file with the right filename on the server.

The strange thing is is that

1. the same code/connection info works on another laptop ok
2. the same connection info works ok using FileZilla when pushing a file
3. the problem occurs on several servers (ie. it's not just one specific destination that has the problem)

Also, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the passive mode (it fails with and without this enabled)

Note, we see ports 20 and 21 open just before the `ftp_close()` using a `netstat -n` on the cmd line. PHP documentation suggests port 20 is the data channel, but we are talking about an INBOUND issue (server to PC) that has the problem. Having added a firewall rule to open up ports 20 and 21 on the INBOUND, I can see that the PHP works. But it's not clear

1. why does PHP want port 20 (whilst FileZilla doesn't),
2. why the other PC doesn't have the same problem (both are company PCs, same model/age/build), and
3. what firewall fix (if any) that I should employ.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks
Abe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the active FTP mode. In the active mode the server tries to connect to the client. In most network configurations, that's not possible as the client machine is usually behind a firewall.

That's why the server fails with:

> Unable to build data connection: Connection refused

It's specifically ProFTPD error message for this situation.

See my article on the [active and passive FTP connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) for details.

---

The code can work on other machines, if they have firewall disabled or if they have rules that allow incoming traffic on unprivileged ports.

FileZilla works because it defaults to the passive mode (as most modern FTP clients do).

---

You have claimed to try the passive mode too, yet to get the same error message.

That's because you are using the `ftp_pasv` call incorrectly.

You have to move the `ftp_pasv` call *after* the `ftp_login`.

```
$user = "*********";
$pass = "*********";
echo "<LI>Connecting as $user/*****";
if (!ftp_login($conn_id, $user, $pass)) { 
    // ...
}

$passive = true;
echo "<LI>Setting Passive Mode=$passive";
ftp_pasv($conn_id, $passive);
```

[The documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php) clearly suggests it:

> Please note that ftp_pasv() can only be called after a successful login or otherwise it will fail.

---

For a similar issue (just with Pure-FTPd), see [PHP upload via FTP - ftp_put() I won't open a connection to x.x.x.x (only to y.y.y.y)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31819695/850848).